# Cannot verify text in textfield - cypress

Tags: cypress

I have got the below textfield:

```
<div _ngcontent-c11="" class="input-container" data-testid="my-textfield"><div _ngcontent-c11="" class="title-container-input"><input _ngcontent-c11="" type="text" ng-reflect-model="my content" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"></div><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></div>
```

I am trying to check that the textfield has the content "my content"
i have tried the below:

```
cy.getBySel('my-textfield').should('have.text', 'my content')
```

also tried:

```
cy.getBySel('my-textfield').should('contain', 'my content')
```

i have tried include also but its not working.

I am getting the below as error:

```
expected <div.input-container> to have text my content, but the text was ''
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is not working.

If i do a type it is working but verifying the textfield content is not working.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can thy this:

```js
cy.getBySel('my-textfield').find('input').should('have.text', 'my content')
//OR
cy.getBySel('my-textfield').find('input').should('have.value', 'my content')
```

Comment: I got the below error if i use value:

expected <div.input-container> to have value my content, but the value was ''

Comment: The second answer worked for me..do you know why i could type directly but i could not verify the content without finding the input?

Comment: Because the input field contains the value attribute.

Comment: so if i had put the testid directly on the input i could have just done:
cy.getBySel('my-textfield').should('have.value', 'my content')

Comment: But with `cy.getBySel('my-textfield')` cypress wan not reaching the input field, hence `.find('input')` was required.